# MailComposer didFinishWith results doesn't work in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mfmailcomposer

I converted my app to swift 3.0 and have a problem with `MailComposeController`. When I call function:

```
`func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}`
```

first of all I have an error with info: 
[image]

what is strange for my, becouse I copy and paste this method from `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`. When I change `Error` to `NSError` it works, but I receive a warning with info, this method needs to be private to avoid this warning.

When I'm in mailComposer and see email and try to tap `Cancel` this controller doesn't disapear. Any solution how to dismiss this controller?

Comment: Same code is working fine for me. Did you clean and rebuild your code?

Comment: yes, I do everything what I can, but still have this stupid error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem because I was importing `RealmSwift`, which has its own `Error` struct.

Fix it by specifying which Error type you want. In this case, `Swift.Error`.

Full Code:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Swift.Error?){
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: F*cking naming issues. It becomes even more funny once you create your own `Error` class