# MFMailComposeViewController back and send button not working

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposer

I tried using the `MFMailComposeViewController` to send an email in my app.

```
let email = "..."

let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()

mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self                
mailComposer.setToRecipients([email])

self.navigationController?.present(mailComposer, animated: true)
```

After running my app the composer screen is showing, but the `cancel` and `send` buttons are not showing. I tried many possible solution, as change `tintColor` in both navigationControllers. For example:

```
mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```

But the "issue" persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: try with `present(mailComposer, animated: true)` instead of `self.navigationController?.present(mailComposer, animated: true)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFMailComposeViewController, Swift 4, Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703157/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-swift-4-xcode-9)

Comment: Did you implement the required delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these code

```
class TechSupportVC: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["desiredEmail@gmail.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("My message")
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                   error: Swift.Error?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        showMailServiceErrorAlert()
        return
    }

    composeVC.setMessageBody("Test credentials: \(firstAndLastNameTextField.text!)\nPhone: \(numberTextField.text!)\n\n\(messageTextView.text!)", isHTML: false)

    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mailComposeDelegate` should be inherited from `UIViewController`.
In other case dismissing `MFMailComposeViewController` not working and crashes.
Seems like Apple bug